# How do I download data from the internet to an S3 bucket via EC2?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, jupyter-notebook

I want to download several large files from the internet (specifically Reddit monthly submissions from the site PushShift) into an S3 bucket. I am SSHed into an EC2 instance and have a Jupyter notebook running.

Ideally I want to be able to write a Python script in Jupyter notebook of my EC2 instance that downloads the file from the internet and then pushes it to my S3 bucket. How would I go about doing this?

Comment: This is essentially two questions "how do I download a file from S3?" and "how do I upload a file to S3?". Both questions have tons of answers already on this site and elsewhere.

Comment: I don't want to download and upload, I essentially want to stream in the files directly from the website into S3 using EC2

Answer (score 2):

It is not possible to "download data from the Internet into Amazon S3".

Amazon S3 is an object storage service. You can upload data to S3 and download data from S3, but **it is not possible to tell S3 to download data from some other location and store it**.

You will need a program running *somewhere* that obtains the data from the Internet, then uploads it (creates an object) in Amazon S3. Such a program could be clever enough to 'stream' the data to S3 by downloading content in-memory and then sending it to S3, without having to save to disk in between, but you would need to write that code.

As to 'where' such a program might run, it would be most efficient to run such code either as an AWS Lambda function or on an Amazon EC2 instance that is in the same region as the Amazon S3 bucket.

Since you are running a Jupyter notebook on an Amazon EC2 instance, it would be easiest to download the file to local storage, then upload it to S3.